# How to trigger primefaces menu item using keyboard

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm implementing a page using primefaces menu, and it needs to be able to navigate using keyboard. I got stuck in selecting menu item which has "outcome" attribute. If you go to the showcase (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml), the very first one "Plain Menu", the last menu item "Internal". How would you select it using keyboard? "Enter" doesn't work.

UPDATE: After a closer examination, the showcase example actually works, as long as you tab through the menu items to the "Internal" and then press "Enter". But for some reason I couldn't make my code work and it's almost exactly the same, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. The following is my code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>IGNORED</title>      
    <h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="styles/styles.css"/>    
</h:head>
<body>  
    <ui:composition>    
        <f:view>
            <h:form id="headerForm">                                            
                <p:menubar >                    
                    <p:submenu label="Links" >
                        <p:menuitem value="Google" url="https://google.com/" />
                        <p:menuitem value="HIPPA Guidelines" url="http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/" />
                        <p:menuitem value="FAQs" url="#" />                         
                    </p:submenu>    

                    <p:submenu label="Help">
                    <p:menuitem  value="On-line Help"  url="#" />
                    </p:submenu>        
                </p:menubar>    
            </h:form>
        </f:view>   
    </ui:composition>
</body>
```

For the menu item "Google", I just couldn't trigger it by the "Enter" key. I'm using primeface 5.1, running on JBoss 6.3 EAP, and I have tried both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: if u inspect element, u can see the menu items are just  <a> anchor tag inside a <ul>  <li>  list, it's working  on the onclick event of <a> , can u replace onclick with 'enter' ?

Comment: I have compared the generated page source between mine and the showcase one. They are almost identical. And I view both page in Firefox. Not sure why they behave differently.

Comment: I know that this is an old post. The reason because they behave differently is that the showcase is always ahead of the release version, which means that if you are using primefaces 5.1 the showcase (at that time) would be in a candidate release ahead with that functionality. I was having the same problem with another component. And I went to the showcase sourcecode and noted that they are using primefaces 6.1.SNAPSHOT which is equivalent to the 6.1.RC3 When I change to that version, problem disappears.